# Dynamic Value for MenuItem in MenuGroup of rich:contextMenu

Tags: jsf-2

**Issue:** I am unable to rerender MenuItems in a MenuGroup of rich:contextMenu on selection of a row in a table.
**Scenario:** I have table of 5 colums and multiple rows. Mouse right click on a row should open contextMenu which has MenuGoup **Items**, this Group should display MenuItem of values of selected row of specific column values.

I am generating a ArrayList in backing bean and have coded like below. But this menuItemPanel is not rendering. And not showing any values.

```
<rich:contextMenu>
<rich:menuItem
    value="View"
    action="#{bakingBean.view}">
</rich:menuItem>
<rich:menuGroup value="Show All Column Values">
    <a4j:outputPanel id="menuItemPanel">
        <c:forEach items="#{bakingBean.items}" var="item">
            <rich:menuItem value="#{item}" 
                           action="#{backingBean.filter}">
                <f:param name="filterVal" value="#{item}"/>
            </rich:menuItem>

        </c:forEach>
    </a4j:outputPanel>
</rich:menuGroup>
```

Comment: Could you supply your table code?